# Change HttpContext.Request.InputStream

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting lot of errors for **HttpRequestValidationException** in my event log.

Is it possible to HTMLEncode all the inputs from override of ProcessRequest on web page. I have tried this but it gives context.Request.InputStream.CanWrite == false always.

Is there any way to HTMLEncode all the feilds when request is made?

```
public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
            {
                if (context.Request.InputStream.CanRead)
                {
                    IEnumerator en = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.GetEnumerator();
                    while (en.MoveNext())
                    {
                        //Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode(en.Current + " = " +
                        //HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[(string)en.Current]));
                    }

                    long nLen = context.Request.InputStream.Length;
                    if (nLen > 0)
                    {
                        string strInputStream = string.Empty;

                        context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[nLen];
                        context.Request.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(nLen));
                        strInputStream = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strInputStream))
                        {
                            List<string> stream = strInputStream.Split('&').ToList<string>();
                            Dictionary<int, string> data = new Dictionary<int, string>();
                            if (stream != null && stream.Count > 0)
                            {
                                int index = 0;
                                foreach (string str in stream)
                                {
                                    if (str.Length > 3 && str.Substring(0, 3) == "txt")
                                    {
                                        string textBoxData = str;
                                        string temp = Server.HtmlEncode(str);
                                        //stream[index] = temp;
                                        data.Add(index, temp);
                                        index++;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (data.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    List<string> streamNew = stream;
                                    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp in data)
                                    {
                                        streamNew[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
                                    }

                                    string newStream = string.Join("", streamNew.ToArray());

                                    byte[] bytesNew = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(newStream);

                                    if (context.Request.InputStream.CanWrite)
                                    {

                                        context.Request.InputStream.Flush();
                                        context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
                                        context.Request.InputStream.Write(bytesNew, 0, bytesNew.Length);
                                        //Request.InputStream.Close();
                                        //Request.InputStream.Dispose();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }


                base.ProcessRequest(context);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to ser the property validateRequest = false and do the necessary validations over user input manually.

`<%@ Page language="c#" validateRequest="false" Codebehind="TestForm.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="TestForm" %>`

Comment: Yes i can do that but i have read online this it is not very safe. If in some instance i forgot to manually validate the input then it can e a potential security issue.

Comment: Afaik validateRequest does not provide any security guarantees by itself - it merely tries to detect the most blatant attempts of abuse. You should use something like an AntiForgeryToken along with AntiXSS to get any real protection. You can deploy AntiXSS to work site-wide, so might want to google that (cant help but the info is out there ;)

Comment: I don't think validateRequest=true is very useful, it just generates an exception that you can't manage, the application just blow up, so IMHO you should use a third party component for validating your input. Much more flexible.

Comment: Request Validation doesn't protect against all XSS attacks and shouldn't be relied upon to block all XSS, but it has its place. Only when you need to accept characters that trigger request validation, you know what request validation does, you know what XSS is, and you know how to protect against XSS on your own, should request validation be disabled.